# Get rid of tabs system in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Is there a mean to disable the tabs system completely? I know you can enable the multi-instance mode from the settings but the feature is problematic since it doesn't disallow a file to open when the latter is already opened in another instance.

If it is really not possible, can I edit a keyboard shortcut to minimize the window? Win+Down Arrow need two hands. I would like a keyboard shortcut that would need only one hand.

Comment: Just to be clear: You're seeking assistance disabling the common UI elements known as "tabs" which ease multi-document handling, and not trying to disable the auto-tab feature that aids in code formatting?

Comment: "You're seeking assistance disabling the common UI elements known as "tabs" which ease multi-document handling" - Yes that's it

Comment: Not sure if this would be helpful, but you may want to look at [this Notepad++ link](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Notepad-like_Behaviour).

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. When opening a file which is already opened in a window, I want Notepad++ put forward that window instead opening a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ was designed to always have at least one tab open (see the source code) so either grab another editor or use Notepad++ in its Post-it view (toggled by <kbd>F12</kbd>) where tabs are hidden.

---

Your second question:

To minimize a window (not only Notepad++) by one hand, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>N</kbd>, what corresponds to the underlined letter (accelerator) for menu item *Minimize*.

Of course, if you grab [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), you can minimize any focused window using keyboard shortcut you want, here it is shown with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
+Esc::  
    WinMinimize A
    Return
```

(`A` is special system variable which stays for currently active window.)

Bonus: The above macro also minimizes windows which do not officially offer their *Minimize* action.